Чёрный экран на винде 10
Я хотела создать виртуалку. Ну типо виртуальную машину, компьютер, сделанный из программного обеспечения грубо говоря. У меня не получалось и я рылась в файлах по советам из интернета, понятия не имела, но я ничего не удаляла и особо не трогала. У меня вылезла ошибка и весь экран чёрный и ничего не работает кроме диспетчера задач. Я еле как перешла в безопасный режим и надеюсь что получится что то с этим сделать. Все туторы, где написано делать что то через пуск или командную строку, а у меня вообще нифига не работа4т, буквально единственное чтт у меня открывалось это диспетчер задач, там нет пуска и других функций про которые писали. Я не хочу потерять все файлы, сносить Винду, откатывать я хз. Если что, то ошибка: sihost.exe unknown hard error. Винда 10. При начальном экране с входом все нормально, а на рабочем столе мигает экран, после чего становится просто чёрным. Курсор есть, ничего нельзя нажать(Пуска, рабочего стола, ничего нет). Только ctrl alt del и shift +перезагрузка, это все что у меня получается нажать. На одной из фотографий в после как раз команда со сканированием, а cmd у меня получилось открыть только через shift+перезагрузку и f6 вроде. И в том прикол, что у меня вряд ли есть установочный носитель.
У меня весь экран черный, и я вот кое как смогла открыть хоть что то, но оно мигает, но ести я вписываю какие то команды то я не могу норм их вписывать, потому что у меня блин короче все сбрасывается, у меня есть пуск но он не работает, все, я наоткрывала и все блин, у меня до этого ничего не было ваще

Чем быстрее отнесёте компьютер в ремонт, тем больше вероятность успешного выхода из ситуации и меньше бестолковая потеря времени.

@FoxFox, какой ещё ремонт? С каких пор там вообще винду ремонтируют?

Экран чёрный включенный или чёрный выключенный? В диспетчере задач на win10 запуск находится в меню файл. Что если запустить explorer? Если не получится, запускай командную строку cmd. И что за виртуальную машину? В какой программе виртуализации? Вообще весь текст вопроса на сгенерированный каким-то генератором текста похож.

Проверьте Win+R или через диспетчер задач. Возможно вы просто вырубили explorer

В ЛЮБОМ ремонте, если это не вшивая забегаловка, не только переустановят Windows, но ещё и поцелуют куда захотите напоследок. Любой каприз за ваши деньги. Деньги надо платить, если охота ковыряться, но неохота учиться. Я понимаю, что хочется нахаляву соскочить, но не всегда получается. В данном случае не получится, поскольку нужных знаний очевидно нет.

Если вам действительно важны данные, следует выполнить следующие шаги:

Успокоиться: Необходимо сохранять спокойствие, чтобы действовать
рационально.
Создать резервную копию диска: Если это еще не сделано, используйте
другой компьютер или загрузочный носитель для создания резервной
копии важных данных. Если первые два пункта вызвали затруднения, лучше обратиться к специалисту, каждая попытка восстановления, может вести к худшему состоянию, вплоть до полной потери данных.


Сначала проведите диагностику:

Проверьте и восстановите системные файлы, если они повреждены
sfc /scannow


Если у вас есть точки восстановления системы, вы можете попробовать восстановить систему до состояния, когда она работала нормально

Если у вас нету точек восстановления, думаю, что нужно использовать загрузочную флешку


